# How to convert a list of vectors of unequal length to a binary data frame?

Tags: r, dplyr

How to convert a list of vectors of unequal length to a binary data frame?  My dataset looks like:

```
> gene_annot
[[1]]
 [1] "lipid binding"           "catalytic activity"      "hydrolase activity"      "lipid metabolic process"
 [5] "cytosol"                 "organelle"               "mitochondrion"           "signaling"              
 [9] "extracellular region"    "extracellular space"    

[[2]]
[1] "extracellular region" "extracellular space"  "organelle"           

[[3]]
[1] "extracellular region" "extracellular space" 

[[4]]
logical(0)

[[5]]
[1] "organelle"                          "nucleus"                            "nucleoplasm"                       
[4] "immune system process"              "defense response to other organism" "protein folding"
```

I'd like to create a column for each label and each cell contains a binary variable indicating whether that label appears in that row. How can I do this in R? For instance, I'd expect such a dataframe:

```
> gene_annot_binary
lipid binding extracellular region

1             1

0             1

0             1

0             0

0             0
```

Answer (score 5):

transpose the following:

```
table(stack(setNames(gene_annot, seq_along(gene_annot))))
                                    ind
values                               1 2 3 4 5
  catalytic activity                 1 0 0 0 0
  cytosol                            1 0 0 0 0
  defense response to other organism 0 0 0 0 1
  extracellular region               1 1 1 0 0
  extracellular space                1 1 1 0 0
  hydrolase activity                 1 0 0 0 0
  immune system process              0 0 0 0 1
  lipid binding                      1 0 0 0 0
  lipid metabolic process            1 0 0 0 0
  mitochondrion                      1 0 0 0 0
  nucleoplasm                        0 0 0 0 1
  nucleus                            0 0 0 0 1
  organelle                          1 1 0 0 1
  protein folding                    0 0 0 0 1
  signaling                          1 0 0 0 0
```

The `t(.)`of the results above is what you need. I did not transpose since its very wide.

Edit:

if you need a data.frame:

```
as.data.frame.matrix(table(stack(setNames(gene_annot, seq_along(gene_annot)))[2:1]))

  catalytic activity cytosol defense response to other organism extracellular region extracellular space
1                  1       1                                  0                    1                   1
2                  0       0                                  0                    1                   1
3                  0       0                                  0                    1                   1
4                  0       0                                  0                    0                   0
5                  0       0                                  1                    0                   0
```

Comment: I misspelled dataframe as table. Could you modify your answer slightly to fit the precise question? Thanks,

Comment: @monotonic check the update

Comment: As in my answer, I believe this drops the empty list elements, which may be undesired?

Answer (score 0):

You didn't provided the data so I created one. Here is an example of what I would do.

```r
library(dplyr, warn.conflicts = FALSE)
library(tidyr)

set.seed(123)

values <- lapply(
  1:10, 
  function(x) {
    sample(letters, size = sample(1:5, 1))
  }
)

values
#> [[1]]
#> [1] "n" "c" "j"
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> [1] "v" "k"
#> 
#> [[3]]
#> [1] "t" "n" "v" "e" "s"
#> 
#> [[4]]
#> [1] "y" "z" "i"
#> 
#> [[5]]
#> [1] "c" "h" "g" "j" "i"
#> 
#> [[6]]
#> [1] "d" "n" "q"
#> 
#> [[7]]
#> [1] "g" "u" "l"
#> 
#> [[8]]
#> [1] "m" "g"
#> 
#> [[9]]
#> [1] "i"
#> 
#> [[10]]
#> [1] "w" "u"

values |>
 lapply(\(x) {
   data.frame(values = x)
 }) |>
  bind_rows(.id = "rowid") |>
  mutate(exists = 1) |> 
  pivot_wider(names_from = values, values_from = exists, values_fill = 0)
#> # A tibble: 10 × 20
#>    rowid     n     c     j     v     k     t     e     s     y     z     i     h
#>    <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#>  1 1         1     1     1     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
#>  2 2         0     0     0     1     1     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
#>  3 3         1     0     0     1     0     1     1     1     0     0     0     0
#>  4 4         0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     1     1     1     0
#>  5 5         0     1     1     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     1     1
#>  6 6         1     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
#>  7 7         0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
#>  8 8         0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
#>  9 9         0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     1     0
#> 10 10        0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
#> # ℹ 7 more variables: g <dbl>, d <dbl>, q <dbl>, u <dbl>, l <dbl>, m <dbl>,
#> #   w <dbl>
```

<sup>Created on 2023-12-01 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

**obs**

This drops the empty list elements, which are not represented as rows of the final data.frame:

**answer**

With `purrr` and `dplyr`, we can:

1-) transform list elements into data.frames with added id (case) columns;

2-) `bind` the list elements into a single data.frame in the long format;

3-) dummify the columns with one of several known methods(pivot_wider, stack, dummy_cols...). I like `pivot_wider` here.

```
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

gene_anot |> 
    imap(\(x,y) tibble(x, case = y)) |> 
    list_rbind() |> 
    pivot_wider(id_cols = case,
                names_from = x,
                values_from = x,
                values_fn = ~ 1,
                values_fill = 0)

# A tibble: 3 × 11
   case `lipid binding` `catalytic activity` `hydrolase activity` lipid metabolic proces…¹ cytosol organelle
  <int>           <dbl>                <dbl>                <dbl>                    <dbl>   <dbl>     <dbl>
1     1               1                    1                    1                        1       1         1
2     2               0                    0                    0                        0       0         1
3     3               0                    0                    0                        0       0         0
# ℹ abbreviated name: ¹​`lipid metabolic process`
# ℹ 4 more variables: mitochondrion <dbl>, signaling <dbl>, `extracellular region` <dbl>,
#   `extracellular space` <dbl>
```

**data**

```
gene_annot <-
list(
    c(
        "lipid binding", "catalytic activity", "hydrolase activity",
        "lipid metabolic process", "cytosol", "organelle", "mitochondrion",
        "signaling", "extracellular region", "extracellular space"
    ),
    c("extracellular region", "extracellular space", "organelle"),
    c("extracellular region", "extracellular space")
)
```

Comment: `unnest(enframe(gene_anot), name)%>%pivot_wider...`